# How to create a before or after Trigger that can catch DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX on Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table like this

```
KD_C KD_PLA KD_T     GABUNG   BERAKHIR    GAJI_PL     BUYOUT
---- ------ ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
C001 MA001  T006       2003       2014      50000    5200000
C002 SC001  T006       2012       2016      65000   20280000
C003 TW001  T006       2005       2018      90000   46800000
C004 TV001  T006       2008       2017      60000   24960000
C005 PC001  T001       2003       2016      80000   24960000
C006 AC001  T001       1996       2014      90000    9360000
C007 DB001  T001       2010       2016      65000   20280000
C008 EH001  T001       2011       2018      85000   44200000
C009 JC001  T002       1996       2014      60000    6240000
C010 SG001  T002       1998       2016      87000   27144000
C011 LS001  T002       2010       2018      81000   42120000
C012 PR001  T002       2004       2016      60000   18720000
C013 JH001  T003       2005       2018      72000   37440000
C014 GC001  T003       2003       2015      65000   13520000
C015 ED001  T003       2010       2018     100000   52000000
C016 GB001  T003       2010       2016      80000   24960000
C017 DG001  T004       2011       2018      73000   37960000
C018 RG001  T004       1992       2014      90000    9360000
C019 PJ001  T004       2011       2018      80000   41600000
C020 RP001  T004       2012       2017      92000   38272000
C021 GB002  T005       2006       2018     102000   53040000
C022 EA001  T005       2011       2015      70000   14560000
C023 HL001  T005       2012       2018      65000   33800000
C024 KW001  T005       2009       2017      67000   27872000
C025 MA001  T005       2017       2022      50000   26000000
C028 MA001  T001       2016       2018      15000    3120000
C029 MA001  T001       2016       2018      15000    3120000
C030 MA001  T001       2016       2018      15000    3120000
```

And then I tried to make a Trigger for updating instead of insert to the table when duplicate a primary key. The primary key is the first coloumn 'KD_CONTRACT'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_TABEL_CONTRACT
BEFORE INSERT ON CONTRACT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    KODE VARCHAR2(20);
    TEMPCARIKODE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT LPAD(TO_NUMBER(NVL(SUBSTR(MAX(KD_CONTRACT),2),0))+1,3,'0') INTO KODE
    FROM CONTRACT;

    SELECT COUNT(KD_CONTRACT) INTO TEMPCARIKODE
    FROM CONTRACT
    WHERE KD_CONTRACT = :NEW.KD_CONTRACT;

    IF(TEMPCARIKODE = 0) THEN       
        :NEW.KD_CONTRACT := 'C'||KODE;
        :NEW.GABUNG := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY'));
        :NEW.BERAKHIR := :NEW.GABUNG + :NEW.BERAKHIR;
        :NEW.BUYOUT := (:NEW.GAJI_PL * 52) * (:NEW.Berakhir-:NEW.Gabung) * 2;
    END IF; 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR at Line 1:');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORA-20003: Data sudah ada, data akan diupdate!');
END;
/
show err;
```

anyway maybe the code show that I tried not to update when the primary key is duplicated. But please the until end first.

it show no error... So the trigger successfully created.
then I tried to insert a duplicated primary key.
`INSERT INTO CONTRACT VALUES('C001','MA001','T001',2013,2,15000,2500000);`

the result

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACT VALUES('C001','MA001','T001',2013,2,15000,2500000)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TUGAS.PK_CONTRACT) violated
```

It did raise ORA-00001 but it never touched the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX and showed nothing or the custom message.
Anyone have Idea? When it never even touch DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then how could I event paste an update query at the when case...
Thanks...
* anyway my oracle is XE or express edition.

Comment: The trigger code won't throw a `dup_val_on_index` so your exception handler will never be called.  The constraint violation check is completely separate from the trigger.  If you want to catch the error, whatever code has the `insert` statement would need to have an exception handler.

Comment: what do you want to get? In first glance you try to insert values with inique `KD_CONTRACT`. If I right, the more suitble is using a sequence.

Comment: @MichaelPiankov Ah that's answer my question.. Then I must find another way. Thanks!

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto: If the question is now unuseful, please remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXCEPTION` block from your trigger will never be executed since your trigger doesn't contain any `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements.
You have to consider `INSTEAD OF` Trigger instead.

Comment: Okay. Can I use the Instead of working also with BEFORE On?